# Picture can't be displayed in php

Tags: php, session, post, get

I am creating a function where user display picture will be retrieve from database after the username is inserted. but i am facing some problem with my code. Please check for me ya ^^
Thank you so much.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$name = $_SESSION['login_username']; // login_username is test123, this is $_SESSION from another .php file
$_SESSION['name'] = $storename;


echo '<img src="display2.php"width="90" height="90"/>'; //this is how i display my picture
?>
```

Display.php(not working)

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$storename = $_SESSION['name']; // is there an error with my $_session statement?
$name = (string)$storename; 

if(!isset($name) || empty($name)){
     die("Please select your image!");

}else{


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customerdetail WHERE customer_username='$name'");
$num_row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $num_row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $content;

 }
}
```

Display.php(working)

```
    $storename = "test123"; // it worked if i store the id in string but not passing from another page.
    $name = (string)$storename;

if(!isset($name) || empty($name)){
     die("Please select your image!");
}else{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customerdetail WHERE customer_username='$name'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
         echo $content;

}
?>
```

Can anyone please help me to figure what goes wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What *is* wrong with it? "Something is wrong" is not an error description.

Comment: Looks like your `$_SESSION['name'] = $storename;` in the first file is empty, from the file comments you say one line above that `// login_username is test123` and in the last (working) file you say that you want `$storename;` to be of value `"test123"`. Maby its a typo and change in your first file line `$name = $_SESSION['login_username'];` to `$storename = $_SESSION['login_username'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very top of your php files (both of them), put this line of code (after the `<?php` tag, of course):

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Yup, i did include this in my "connection.php" already ^^

Comment: Okay. I see that you're trying to display image in display2.php, while your script is in display.php

Comment: thank you ~~ i really missed out the session_start() in my display.php. such a stupid mistake.. lol

Answer (score 0):

`header('Content-type: image/jpg');` declares that the output will be jpg image since the code runs from `<img src="">`

It's impossible to display text as iamges

Comment: Sorry, i am weak to programming, can u please explain a little bit more in detail ? thank you so much ^.^

Comment: Isn't <img src=""> the correct method used to display the image ?

Comment: If it's like this, if you don't include that bunch of line than the output type will be text/html (CMIIW) and of course you can't "call" html file using img tag. If you include it so the type is image and, it works!

Comment: I'm not good at english, so sorry if the word is bad

Comment: It's fine. Can you please state a example ? Because i dun really understand. If i assign the value for &storename, it works. When i pass in another value from previous page to $storename, it just simply cant work.

PS: I did pass value from login1.php to login2.php. but when i pass value from login2.php to display.php. it seems like there is an error.

Comment: I'm not good explaining though. I think you should learn more PHP